# Same sql query return two differents results

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to understand, why when I run same sql query twice on oracle 10G database , in interval of 40 minutes, I had two different results. The results are return in excel file.
What can be the cause of this difference?

Comment: The difference is probably that some DML (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) or DDL (TRUNCATE) has been performed on your table... however without access to your production systems and even then sometimes without you having auditing enabled no one here will be able to tell... In other words the cause could be almost anything at all done by anyone who has access or any process which runs on your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be related to a power network during the extraction of the database. Or other Could Be almost anything at all done by anyone Who has access or Any process All which runs on your database during your extraction.